# Typo3 7.2 add file reference to extension model

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, filereference

I'm using Typo 7.2 and am looking for an answer to the following question:

*How to add a generated File as FileReference programmatically to an extension model?*

First some infos regarding my achievements/tries.

**DONE** A command controller runs over folders, looks for a specific image and creates a blurred file via GraphicFunctions. The generated file is added to the storage as a standalone simple file and appears in the sys_file table.

```
$fileObject = $posterStorage->addFile(
  $convertResult[3],
  $posterStorage->getFolder($blurFolderName),
  $newFileName);
```

**PARTIALLY DONE.** Now I need to add the generated file as a file reference to my model. The problem is, that I'm able to do this, but only by hacking core - not acceptable - and unable to do it the right way. The model says:

```
public function addPosterWebBlur(
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $posterWebBlur
) {
  $this->posterWebBlur->attach($posterWebBlur);
}
```

So I succeeded by extending the FileReference class:

```
class FileReference extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference {
  public function setFile(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File $falFile) {
    $this->$uidLocal = (int)$falFile->getUid();
  }
}
```

The reference does not get established and I just get the following error in the backend:

```
Table 'db_name.tx_ext_name_domain_model_filereference' doesn't exist.
```

**UPDATE**
After integrating the data from Frans in ext_typoscript_setup.txt, the model can be saved, creates an sys_file_reference entry and acts nicely in the backend. But there are a few points open to fulfill all needs:

1. The sys_file_reference table does not contain a value for table_local, whereas all the entries generated by a backend user hold sys_file as value.
2. The same applies to l10n_diffsource which holds some binary large object. This entry gets inserted in the sys_file_reference table after saving the record manually via backend.
3. The pid of the file_reference has to be set via setPid($model->getPid()), is that okay?
4. The cruser_id is always set to zero. Is this the correct way?
5. When trying to delete a file (which was added to a model with the backend possibilities) via the file manager, I get a warning, that references to this file exist. This does not apply to the fileReference added programmatically. Also the references listed under the file (when clicking on "Info" for a generated file in the backend file manager) don't get listed. They get listed, when I enter the "sys_file" value in the sys_file_reference table by hand.
6. As Helmut Hummels example holds additional data, I'm wondering, if I just miss some stuff.
7. The file reference is used inside an object storage, but as the addImage function only calls objectStorage->attach I think this should be okay and no additional objectStorage actions are neccessary. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the extbase persistence layer to use the correct table. See for instance this example https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/blob/master/ext_typoscript_setup.txt

gr. Frans

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer 1)
See
https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_uploadexample_domain_model_example.php#L128
You should probably check the TCA definition for your posterWebBlur field. Second param of getFileFieldTCAConfig()
TT